# How to vectorize slicing operations on torch tensors?

Tags: python, torch

I have a bunch of variables expressed by list comprehensions. I want to turn it into `torch.tensor`, so far I got

```
import torch
n = 10
y = torch.rand(n ** 2, requires_grad=True)
one_node_per_position = torch.FloatTensor([sum(y[k:k + n]) - 1 for k in range(0, n ** 2, n)])
one_node_per_point = torch.FloatTensor([sum(y[j::n]) - 1 for j in range(n)])
connectivity = torch.FloatTensor([sum(y[k:k + n]) - sum(y[k - n:k]) for k in range(n, n ** 2, n)])
```

But it obviously doesn't look good. How can I rewrite it to get advantage of vectorization for further using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`as_strided`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.as_strided.html) operator to generate views of the original array using vectorized operations, and apply the sum to these views:

```py
import torch

n = 10
y = torch.rand(n**2, requires_grad=True)

# Vectorized version
vec_one_node_per_position = torch.as_strided(y, (n, n), (n, 1)).sum(axis=-1) - 1
vec_one_node_per_point = torch.as_strided(y, (n, n), (1, n)).sum(axis=-1) - 1
vec_connectivity = (
    torch.as_strided(y, (n - 1, n), (n, 1), n).sum(axis=-1) 
    - torch.as_strided(y, (n - 1, n), (n, 1)).sum(axis=-1)
)


# Ensure consistency with comprehension-based version
one_node_per_position = torch.FloatTensor([sum(y[k : k + n]) - 1 for k in range(0, n**2, n)])
one_node_per_point = torch.FloatTensor([sum(y[j::n]) - 1 for j in range(n)])
connectivity = torch.FloatTensor([sum(y[k : k + n]) - sum(y[k - n : k]) for k in range(n, n**2, n)])


assert torch.isclose(vec_one_node_per_position, one_node_per_position).all()
assert torch.isclose(vec_one_node_per_point, one_node_per_point).all()
assert torch.isclose(vec_connectivity, connectivity).all()
```